# store value from checkbox into string if checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to store value from checkbox into string

```
 <label style="color:black; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px" href="#">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="diet.v1" ng-true-value="'&diet=high-fiber'" ng-false-value="''" />High-Fiber</label>
```

How do i get value from `ng-true-value` (when it's checked) to string so i can use it ?
when i try something like this console.log(diet.v1); in js it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following working sample code with ng-true-value, ng-false-value.

```html
 <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Example - example-checkbox-input-directive-production</title>
          
        
          <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
          
        
          
        </head>
        <body ng-app="checkboxExample">
          <script>
          angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
              $scope.diet = {
               v1 : ''
             };
            }]);
        </script>
        <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
          <label>Value:
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="diet.v1"
                   ng-true-value="'&diet=high-fiber'" ng-false-value="''">
           </label><br/>
          <tt>value = {{diet.v1}}</tt><br/>
         </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: this doesent change value of .value1 between what i need and empty string when i click checkbox

Comment: value1 is just for reference. checkboxModel.value2 is based on your requirement.

Comment: i know that but when i put my own costum value and try clicking checkbox, that value doesent change between ng-true-value and ng-false-value for some reason

Comment: Please check the plunker, I have used same like your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/GIWTaXpuTUIaMX9aXx6L

Comment: The code snippet also added, please check. You can also post your code in plunker for further check.